# How to create an arrow morph in smalltalk80 (squeak) programmatically?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I need to draw an arrow morph from center of one given morph to center of another given morph.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is it exactly that is causing you trouble?

Comment: I'm trying to use the PolygonMorph in order to create a simple arrow morph: line + head. 

I know that it should be simple - for some reason can't find any manual on how to do it.

(13 years hands on in software industry. smalltalk. simple stuff. embarrassing. I know.)

Comment: Don't feel embarrassed... We have an ArrowHeadBuilder class with 15 methods to address something similar. Yes, 11 of them are 1 line methods, but that was the easiest way to write the algorithm to find the points. Juan Vuletich was the author

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `a` and `b` are your morphs:

```
arrow := (LineMorph from: a center to: b center color: Color red width: 2) makeForwardArrow.
arrow openInWorld.
```

If you want to update the position after the morphs move, do this:

```
arrow setVertices: {a center. b center}
```